# Parallel Coordinates Riddle: Is it possible to go from line to point to line .. and eventually come back to the same line?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

For clarification: For a line that is represented in the Euclidean plane as:
$l: a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3 = 0$ We can represent it using parallel coordinates by using the transformation $$ A =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & d &0 \\ 
 0&0  &-1 \\ 
1 &  1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Wherein $d$ is the distance between the $x_1$ and $x_2$ axes. This transformation gives us a point in parallel coordinates (a duality). Given such a point, we can go back to a line in the Euclidean plane using the transformation $$ B =\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 &0 \\ 
 0&0  &-d \\ 
d & 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
.

The question is, after a finite amount of transormations $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow ... \rightarrow B$, will I get back to the line I started with. In other words, is $A \cdot B \cdot ... \cdot B = I_3$? What about if I start with a point and not a line.

My thinking is this: First off, $d = 1$ or else it'll never happen because of determinant reasons. Then, I calculated the matrix $AB$ ($d=1$ and it doesn't seem to me like it will ever be $I_3$, but I'm not sure how to prove it or if I'm on the right track. I also think I'm mistaken somewhere..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can I get some clarification here: Are you talking about ABAB...AB, or about ABBB...BB ?

Comment: We're talkign about ABABA...BABAB

Comment: Okay. I will point out though that we are actually talking about BABA...BA, as you apply matrices from right to left, and you start by applying A.

Comment: You're right! I need to figure out both cases though.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter: $(BA)^n = I_3$ if and only if $(AB)^n = I_3$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I figured out why it will never be, I commented below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am changing my answer because it appears you are talking about a given $B$, rather than trying to undo $A$ as I originally supposed.

In this case, unless $d = \pm 1$, it will never be $I_3$. Because $\det A = -d$ and $\det B = d^2$, we see that the determinant of any finite product of them is $\pm d^k$ for some $k$. As $\det I_3 = 1$, the only possible way to get $I_3$ as a product is to have either $d = 1$ and have an even number of $A$s in the product, or have $d = -1$ (in which case there is no resriction on the number of $A$s).

Of course, this doesn't say it is possible for $d = \pm 1$, just that it is impossible for any other value of $d$.

Comment: My bad! I'll edit it with the given $B$.

Comment: I've changed my post as I think I was mis-interpreting your post originally. (Not entirely sure I'm interpreting it correctly now.)

Comment: I'm sorry about my mistake. For $d = 1$, I think that $(AB)^k$ will never be $I_3$ because it's a matrix with 3 eigenvalues that are 1 that isn't equal to id.

Comment: If $d$ = 1, then the eigenvalues of $AB$ are $1, i, -i$. If $d = -1$, then the three eigenvalues are $-1, 1, 1$. I don't think you can conclude from just this that no power of $AB$ is $I_3$, though obviously even powers would be required for $d = -1$, and a multiple of $4$ for $d = 1$